# What is the relation between numFeatures in HashingTF in Spark MLlib and actual number of terms in a document?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

Is there any relation between numFeatures in HashingTF in Spark MLlib and the actual number of terms in a document(sentence)?

```
List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
  RowFactory.create(0.0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  RowFactory.create(0.0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
  RowFactory.create(1.0, "Logistic regression models are neat")
);
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
  new StructField("label", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())
});
Dataset<Row> sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words");
Dataset<Row> wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData);

int numFeatures = 20;
HashingTF hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
  .setNumFeatures(numFeatures);

Dataset<Row> featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData);
```

As mentioned in the documentation of Spark Mllib, HashingTF converts each sentence into a feature vector of having numFeatures as length. 
What will happen if each document here, in this case, sentence contains thousands of terms? What should be the value of numFeatures? How to calculate that value?

Answer (score 8):

`HashingTF` uses the [hashing trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) that does not maintain a map between a word/token and its vector position. The transformer takes each word/taken, applies a hash function ([MurmurHash3_x86_32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash)) to generate a long value, and then performs a simple module operation (% 'numFeatures')  to generate an Integer between 0 and `numFeatures`. The resulting value is the index that will be incremented in the feature Vector.

Given the nature of the algorithm, if `numFeatures` is less than the actual number of distinct words/tokens in the DataFrame you are guaranteed to have an 'incorrect' frequency for at least 1 token (i.e. different tokens will hash to the same bucket). NOTE: Even with numFeatures >= vocabularySize collisions 'might' still happen.

What's the best value for `numFeatures`? I would take a number greater than the size of your 'vocabulary' (do not worry too much about space as the features are stored in a [ml.linalg.SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector)). Note that (see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF)):

> Since a simple modulo is used to transform the hash function to a column index, it is advisable to use a power of two as the numFeatures parameter; otherwise the features will not be mapped evenly to the columns.

If you prefer to have an exact frequency count then take a look at [CountVectorizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#countvectorizer)

Comment: Just checking if i've understood this properly - If i applied the function to a new dataset with the same numfeatures parameter, would an algorithm i trained on a previous dataset be applicable to the new one?

Comment: Setting numFeatures to a number greater than the vocab size doesn't make sense. Conversely, you want to set numFeatures to a number way lower than the vocab size. Because one of the main motivations for using hashingTF is to reduce the number of dimensions by sacrificing some collision. In that sense, the baseline method is CountVectorizer which will generate vocab-size vectors. One way to find the best numFeatures for your dataset is to increase and monitor the accuracy of your ML task. I had good results with 512 where the vocab size was ~60k.